# How to auto select date in input type date field

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have two `input type="date"` fields and I want to auto select second date according to first date.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="first">
<input type="date" id="second">
```

How to auto select 7 days later date on second input type and want to disabled date before today on second input type date.

Comment: any code that you have tried so far

Comment: i have no idea how to do this

Comment: what is your requirement, auto select date from first or any other

Comment: You can use jquery date range pick plugin.

Comment: 7 days after date from first one

Comment: Ever heard of Moment.js? This should solve your purpose https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Comment: ok thank you this will solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you to solve your problem, check a deep look :D

```js
jQuery(document).ready(()=>{
  jQuery('#first').change(()=>{
    
    var _date = jQuery('#first').val();
   
    var res = new Date(_date).setTime(new Date(_date).getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var month = new Date(res).getMonth()+1;
    var day = new Date(res).getDate();
    var output = new Date(res).getFullYear() + '-' +
   (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
    (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
    
    jQuery('#second').val(output);

})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="first">
<input type="date" id="second">
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple jquery, using [stepUp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_range_stepup.asp) method to add days

```js
today = new Date();
day = today.getDate()
month = today.getMonth() + 1
year = today.getFullYear();

day = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;
month =  month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
today = new String(year + '-' + month + '-' + day)
$("#second")[0].min = today;

$('#first').on('change', function(e){
  date = new Date($('#first').val());
  $('#second')[0].valueAsNumber = date.setDate(date.getDate())
  $("#second")[0].stepUp(7);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="first">
<input type="date" id="second">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="first" onchange="setdate()">
<input type="date" id="second">

<script>
 function setdate(){
  var tt =$('#first').val();

     var newdate = new Date(tt);
     var add_value = 7;

     newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + add_value);   
 
     var dd = newdate.getDate();
     var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
     var y = newdate.getFullYear();

     if((mm.toString().length)==1){
      var mm = '0'+mm;
     }
     if((dd.toString().length)==1){
      var dd = '0'+dd;
     }
     
     var someFormattedDate = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

     $('#second').val(someFormattedDate);
 
 }
</script>
```